# Why Does Bootstrap Label appear in wrong place?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't make out the convoluted logic behind where `<label>` elements are actually placed.   I want a form with two rows.  I want a label for each row, and then an input box after that.  I would like the responsive behavior that when the viewport gets narrow, the label appears just above the input.  When wide the label is left and the input right.

Works OK most of the time, but sometimes the `<label>` behaves so strange and I struggle trying to just get a simple two row form to work.  Here is the sample:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="well">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
            Reminder
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-5 container">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 container">
            Minutes before meeting
          </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Form Control TYPE Begin -->
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="radio radio-primary">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" value="1"
                  class="form-control">
                  Circle Meeting
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" value="2"
                  class="form-control">
                  Operational Meeting
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

I just spent 15 minutes making this selfstanding, so you should be able to put this in a file and load it directly into a browser.

The result is that instead of putting the label on the left, it is put in the row above (in that DIV) instead of in the DIV that the label is declared in.  I have tried a number of manipulations, but the label seems to want to "jump" out of the DIV it is defined in, and into the DIV before it, and that messes up the layout of both DIV tags which are meant to be rows in a form.

[image: image showing defective layout]

See that the "Type" label does NOT appear on the left edge, but rather floating in the previous DIV and with the last element within that DIV.

Also the layout of the radio buttons and the labels on them are very *inconvenient*.

I would very much appreciate if someone can explain what is going on, and how to avoid this in the future.  (Not just a solution to this case, but an explanation that will allow me to avoid future cases as well.)

Comment: Ok, so I tried it, and you should close of "<div class="well"> before the next "form group" with another "</div>" to fix the Type-part from floating to the previous div.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it; Set the form and fields tags around your form; some class changes

```
  <div class="well">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">
            Reminder
          </label>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="textinput" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            Minutes before meeting
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-1">
              <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="1">
                  Circle Meeting
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-2">
              <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-2" value="2">
                  Operational Meeting
            </label>
        </div>
     </div>
     </fieldset>
     </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hmmmph.   That works.  The original has those tags in it.  I removed them when trying to minimize to the smallest set.  Now I can't reproduce the problem in the original (much bigger) source.  Apparently I never actually had a problem.   Can you explain the logic behind needing this, and why the layout is so strange?